# How to keep Boolean values when converting XML to JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml, json.net

I'm working with JSON. When I convert XML to JSON it does not keep Boolean values as Boolean. It gives double quotes for boolean values.  I'm using Json.Net to do the conversion.

This is my XML:

```
<root>
  <file>
    <field_name>contains_mrn</field_name>
    <field_value>true</field_value>
 </file>
 </root>
```

Output:

```
{
  "file": {
    "field_name": "contains_mrn",
    "field_value": "true"
  }
}
```

But my expectation is:

```
{
  "file": {
    "field_name": "contains_mrn",
    "field_value": true
  }
}
```

Comment: And your code that converts is...? XML has no types (well, if we ignore XML Schema for a moment) so there's no good way to know that "true" should be treated as a JSON boolean here rather than a string. Somewhere, some code is going to have to make the call that that's how we want things for the strings "true" and "false". (The same problem exists in some form for numbers.)

Comment: Most people use one and zero for true and false in JSON.

Comment: @jdweng They do? That sounds like conjecture to me.  What is your source?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take the longer route if Json is your final desired output. You need to convert Deserialize your XML first and then Serialize it to JSON.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
var obj = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(str));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Where Class definitions are as follows.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="file")]
public class File 
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName="field_name")]
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "field_name")]
   public string Field_name { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "field_value")]
   [XmlElement(ElementName="field_value")]
   public bool Field_value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="root")]
public class Root 
{
  [XmlElement(ElementName="file")]
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "file")]
  public File File { get; set; }
}
```

This would give you the desired output.

```
{
  "file": {
    "field_name": "contains_mrn",
    "field_value": true
  }
}
```